# Titanium mobile application running error

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, titanium-mobile

With titanium studio, when I tried to run first application it was encountered with the problem.
I think My virus gard removed some python files

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning the project from inside Titanium Studio and re-build it.

If that doesn't correct the issue, try reinstalling the Titanium SDK, or Titanium Studio.

Your virus guard should have an option to ignore some files, try to add the Titanium dependencies to that list to be sure that doesn't happend again.